# write some bytes to a bluetooth device

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I have a new wireless keyboard whose F-keys default to media keys. I want to use the F keys like normal function keys. I found [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/majenkotech/kbswitch/master/perl/kbswitch) with which a user manages to write some bytes to the device's Unifying Receiver (an USB dongle) to make the keyboard switch.

Since I'm on Bluetooth, I was hoping that I could send the same bytes to the Bluetooth device. But I admit that I don't know neither whether my theory makes any sense nor what I'm doing.

I found out the MAC address of the device with

`bluetoothctl devices`

Then I bound it using rfcomm:

`sudo rfcomm bind 0 DF:9B:72:06:98:B1`

then sending the bytes using echo:

`echo -n -e '\x10\x02\x0c\x1c\x00\x00\x00' > /dev/rfcomm0`

but the shell then hangs until I press ctrl-c, with nothing happening.

Any idea what I could do?

Comment: the BT keyboard is fine.. I just want to send a command to it. Let me clarify the original post :)